# Using the result of a for loop statement for a condition in an else if statement

Tags: javascript, loops, if-statement

My third else if statement condition should be the result of the for loop. How do I use the loop for the condition?

```
        //If player clicks centre on first move go in corner square
        if (current[4] === playerToken && this.state.stepNumber === 1) {
          let move = cornerSquares[Math.floor(Math.random() * cornerSquares.length)];
          drawSquare(move);
        } 
        //If player clicks corner square on first move go in centre square
        else if (this.state.stepNumber === 1) {
          for (let i = 0; i < cornerSquares.length; i++){
            if (current[cornerSquares[i]] === playerToken) {
              drawSquare(4);
            }
          }
        }
        //If player or computer has 2 in a row, place in 3rd square to win or block
        else if (/*CONDITION OF THE BELOW FOR LOOP*/) {
          for (let i = 0; i < twoInRow.length; i++) {
            const [a, b, c] = twoInRow[i];  
            if (current[a] && current[a] === current[b]) {
              drawSquare(c);
            }
          }
        }
        //Place in random empty square
        else {
         //code to randomly place x/o in random square
        }
      }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`My third else if statement condition should be the result of the for loop` => Nope.

`if {} else ...` are evaluated at the same time, and the first which validates condition is taken. If you want conditions evaluated one after one, you have to use `if {} if {} ...`

Comment: Thanks, I got too caught up in the sequence - multiple if statements works just fine :)

Answer (score 1):

If you can define `c` outside like this then you can take the loop out to a separate function like this:

```
    let c = null;
    //If player clicks centre on first move go in corner square
    if (current[4] === playerToken && this.state.stepNumber === 1) {
      let move = cornerSquares[Math.floor(Math.random() * cornerSquares.length)];
      drawSquare(move);
    } 
    //If player clicks corner square on first move go in centre square
    else if (this.state.stepNumber === 1) {
      for (let i = 0; i < cornerSquares.length; i++){
        if (current[cornerSquares[i]] === playerToken) {
          drawSquare(4);
        }
      }
    }
    //If player or computer has 2 in a row, place in 3rd square to win or block

    //in JS you can assign inside of an 'if' statement
    //an assignment evaluates to the value assigned
    //so we assign the result of 'hasTwoInRow' to 'c' and check if it's not null
    else if ((c = hasTwoInRow(twoInRow,current)) !== null) {
      drawSquare(c);
    }
    //Place in random empty square
    else {
     //code to randomly place x/o in random square
    }
  }

  function hasTwoInRow(twoInRow,current) {
    for (let i = 0; i < twoInRow.length; i++) {
      const [a, b, c] = twoInRow[i];  
      if (current[a] && current[a] === current[b]) {
        return c;
      }
    return null;
  }
```

Comment: Thanks @Dmitry - was looking at creating a function like this, passing C was my trouble. So easy once shown :)

Comment: @Nims you're welcome. Please upvote if it was helpfull.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `move` variable to have an indication where you found a move or not yet, and use that in the next `if` (without `else`):

```
let move = null;
//If player clicks centre on first move go in corner square
if (current[4] === playerToken && this.state.stepNumber === 1) {
    let move = cornerSquares[Math.floor(Math.random() * cornerSquares.length)];
} 
//If player clicks corner square on first move go in centre square
else if (this.state.stepNumber === 1) {
    for (let i = 0; i < cornerSquares.length; i++){
        if (current[cornerSquares[i]] === playerToken) {
            move = 4;
            break; // Don't lose time on looping further
        }
    }
}
//If player or computer has 2 in a row, place in 3rd square to win or block
if (move === null) {
    for (let i = 0; i < twoInRow.length; i++) {
        const [a, b, c] = twoInRow[i];  
        if (current[a] && current[a] === current[b]) {
            move = c;
            break; // Don't lose time on looping further
        }
    }
}
//Place in random empty square
if (move === null {
    //code to randomly place x/o in random square
    move = // your logic here
}
// Perform move
drawSquare(move);
```

Comment: Thanks @trincot - I also like this method. So many ways to do the same task with code :)